# Gradle DSL method not found: 'dimension()'

Tags: android, gradle

I am using **AndroidPdfViewer** library due to this my APK size is increased. To solve that problem I am trying to create multiple APK depends on the architecture. This is the first time I am splitting APK.I got an error as I mention below.

Is any line I have to add to the **gradle-wrapper.properties** file.

**App-level build.gradle:**

```
        android {
        compileSdkVersion 26
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.root.aranachat"
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 26
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        flavorDimensions "tier", "minApi"
        productFlavors {
            x86 {
                ndk {
                    abiFilter "x86"
                }
                dimension "tier"
            }
            mips {
                ndk {
                    abiFilter "mips"
                }
                dimension "tier"
            }
            armv7 {
                ndk {
                    abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
                }
                dimension "minApi"
            }
            arm {
                ndk {
                    abiFilter "armeabi"
                }
                dimension "minApi"
            }
            fat
            dimension "minApi"
        }

    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.0.0-beta.5'

        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    }
```

**project-level build.gradle**

```
buildscript {

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Error message:

```
Error:(46, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'dimension()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'AranaChat' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
<a href="open.wrapper.file">Open Gradle wrapper file</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>
```

Comment: try removing the last line of your productFlavors block (below 'fat') - dimension is not valid here. it has to belong to a flavor def.

Comment: ok, it's working now but still, my apk size is 10mb in which 6 MB is lib folder any idea what I should do.

Comment: umm, ok you might want to consider using abiSplits instead of multiple flavors: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html#configure-abi-split